# Issue using setTag and getTag in ListView from SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, onclick, simpleadapter

I have to execute multiple actions with items from a listview, ex. a Button, this button have to get a text that I set on TextView from jSON, so I tried using setTag and getTag, but I'm getting Null the value of **"CODE"**. Here my snipped code, thanks in advance.

the View of my ExtendedsimpleAdapter extends Simpleadapter .java

```
public class ExtendedSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> map;
String[] from;
int layout;
int[] to;
Context context;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
public ExtendedSimpleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data,
        int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    layout = resource;
    map = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) data;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
return this.createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, layout);
}

private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent, int resource) {
View v;
AtomPaymentHolder holder = null;
if (convertView == null) {
    v = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

} else {
    v = convertView;

    holder = new AtomPaymentHolder();

    holder.share = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.share_item_session_button);
    holder.share.setTag(position);

    holder.ws_name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ws_name_item_session_text);
    holder.ws_name.setTag(position);

//  holder.img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_session);
//  holder.img.setTag(holder.atomPayment);
    v.setTag(holder);

}

this.bindView(position, v);

return v;
}

public static class AtomPaymentHolder {
ImageView img;
//TextView flip;
//TextView code;
TextView ws_name;
ImageButton share;
}
private void bindView(int position, View view) {
final HashMap<String, Object> dataSet = map.get(position);
if (dataSet == null) {
    return;
}

final ViewBinder binder = super.getViewBinder();
final int count = to.length;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
    if (v != null) {
        final Object data = dataSet.get(from[i]);
        String text = data == null ? "" : data.toString();
        if (text == null) {
            text = "";
        }

        boolean bound = false;
        if (binder != null) {
            bound = binder.setViewValue(v, data, text);
        }

        if (!bound) {
            if (v instanceof Checkable) {
                if (data instanceof Boolean) {
                    ((Checkable) v).setChecked((Boolean) data);
                } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                    // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                    // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                    setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() +
                            " should be bound to a Boolean, not a " +
                            (data == null ? "<unknown type>" : data.getClass()));
                }
            } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                setViewText((TextView) v, text);
            } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                if (data instanceof Integer) {
                    setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Integer) data);                            
                } else if (data instanceof Bitmap){
                    setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Bitmap)data);
                } else {
                    setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                        " view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
private void setViewImage(ImageView v, Bitmap bmp){
v.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
}
```

Here my other Activity, snipped code, here I try to do the action when Button "Share" is onClick, but ***CODE*** value is null when I'm debugging

```
public void shareOnClickHandler(View v) {

    AtomPaymentHolder CODE = (AtomPaymentHolder)v.getTag();
    String codigo= CODE.ws_name.getText().toString();


}
```

Other ex. is when I tap Share Button, the ImgView has to change for another img, and this URL img was set on textView, so I have to read this textVieW, get string and change ImgView. so I need to setTag and getTag on items properly, that's is my problem. TY

Comment: please post full code of both your activity and adapter

Comment: without click you canot get the position

Comment: Done all code for Adapter , code for activity first part is just a request for a WS, nothing special -@Dhairya

Comment: onClickHandler is implement on layout
--android:onClick="shareOnClickHandler"-- - @Amardeep